# apache2 ip redirect conflicting with subdomain redirect

Tags: web-server, ip, redirect, subdomain, apache2

so visiting my website `example.com` works as intended.
I successfully configured a redirect so that `abc.example.com` will redirect to `example.com/abc`.

The config file looks like this `abc.example.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName abc.example.com
    RedirectPermanent / https://example.com/abc
</VirtualHost>
```

**My problem:**

When visiting my website by typing the raw IP address into the browser I will also be redirected to `example.com/abc` which is not the desired behavior.
The raw IP in the browser should drop me of at `example.com`

Here is the `example.com.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

What do I need to change so that when I type in my IP address `example.com` gets served instead of `abc.example.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because one of your vhosts is acting as the default.  When the `ServerName` at server level (i.e. not in a `VirtualHost` block) matches one inside a `VirtualHost`, that will be the default.  If none is set, then it is typically the first vhost.

Assuming you are using an all-vhost config, the answer is to set the `ServerName example.com` (and the corresponding `Listen`) outside the vhost block.

Reference: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html

> Main host goes away
>
> Any request that doesn't match an existing is handled by the global server configuration, regardless of the hostname or ServerName.
>
> When you add a name-based virtual host to an existing server, and the virtual host arguments match preexisting IP and port combinations, requests will now be handled by an explicit virtual host. In this case, it's usually wise to create a default virtual host with a ServerName matching that of the base server. New domains on the same interface and port, but requiring separate configurations, can then be added as subsequent (non-default) virtual hosts.

Comment: Thank you! That lead me into the right direction.
My understanding is that the default site that is served when entering the IP is determined by whatever .conf file comes first in the sites-enabled folder.

What I did now is to cp the example.conf file into a 000-default.conf file and enable the site with a2ensite.